# integrate sharepoint 2010 with tfs2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

My colleagues have installed TFS2010 and Sharepoint Services 3.0

Instead of using Sharepoint Services, I'd like to install Sharepoint2010. How feasible is that ? Will I be able to move the existing sharepoint collections created with the current version to the new version of Sharepoint. How does it integrate with TFS2010 ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can safely upgrade SharePoint to 2010 and everything will continue to work fine.